# Ansible cronjob - adding a timestamp to filename

Tags: cron, ansible, timestamp

I am trying to write an Ansible task that does a daily backup of our database and timestamps the name of the file.

```
- name: Run cronjob to backup database.
  become_user: postgres
  cron:
    name: "Export database"
    special_time: daily
    job: pg_dump -U db_user -W -F t db_name > filename.tar
```

I tried simply appending $(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S) to filename.tar e.g

```
filename-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S).tar
```

However this wont work as the value of the date is set only once when the task is ran, leading to every filename having a timestamp of when the ansible task was ran.

I'm looking for around this, and to allow this job to generate a new timestamp for each filename.

Answer (score 0):

In general, we have a practice of creating shell scripts to handle database backups. This allows us to capture exit code(s), and log/send alerts accordingly.

Though a simple one with just one `pg_dump` command will do, something similar as below should be possible:

Example:

**db-backup.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

DB_USER="dbuser"
DB_PASSWORD="dbpassword"
DB_NAME="db_name"
BACKUP_FILE="db-backup-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S).tar"

cmd="pg_dump -U ${DB_USER} -W -F t ${DB_NAME} > ${BACKUP_FILE}"

if $cmd; then
  # do something
else
  # do something else
fi
```

Then in Ansible, copy this script to target, and create `cron` job to run this script.

```yaml
# Copying to temp directory for example
- name: copy database backup script
  copy:
    src: 'db-backup.sh'
    dest: '/tmp/db-backup.sh'
    mode: '0755'
    owner: 'postgres'
    group: 'postgres'

- name: run cronjob to backup database
  become_user: postgres
  cron:
    name: 'Export database'
    special_time: 'daily'
    job: '/tmp/db-backup.sh'
```